# loading javascript async and listener when script is finished downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to download a script async using the html 5:

```
 <script async type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
```

however I wanted to know when this script has been loaded and I wanted to fire an event like this:

```
 var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
 evt.initEvent("jsLoadedEvent",true,true);
 document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

how do I do this?
I can't also use .ready(), because ready will be called after all of the image is loaded, etc. I wanted an event where just this script is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
  var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
  evt.initEvent("jsLoadedEvent",true,true);
  $(document).dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: "I can't also use .ready(), because ready will be called after all of the image is loaded"   Why do you want an event to fire after jQuery loaded, but prior to images loading?  Maybe you should load the images via jQuery then?